# Export SRTM30 Dem file as 3d

Tags: dem, arcscene, srtm

I have downloaded some SRTM Dem files here: http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM30//srtm30
They are from the USGS site.

I would like to export them as 3d.

I have ran through a few tutorials online, e.g.

1. http://www.brocku.ca/maplibrary/proc...iew/3dview.htm
2. http://prod.library.utoronto.ca/maplib/3D.pdf

   But still don't get it.

Question:

1. so are the SRTM DEM files exportable to be viewed in 3d via Arcscene/ Arcmap?
2. how do you do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you downloaded the data what format did it come in?  By definition, if the data is a raster format, it can be considered 3D data, as it has a x,y,z value.  If you are looking to have it extruded in ArcScene then you will want to do a few of the following things.

Assuming your data is in a usable raster format (ie: GeoTiff) then you will want to do the following:
 - Open the Properties of the data in ArcScene and change the Symbology (ie: Standard Dev. 2 and change the statistics to From Current Display Extent
 - On the Base Heights Tab change the radio buttom from No elevation values from a surface to Floating on a custom surface and choose the SRTM raster file (this will make the raster have 3D visual appeal
 - Finally you can play with the visual rendering which is located under the Rendering tab.  The Higher the rendering, the more memory it needs from your computer and graphics card.

Comment: Let me try this out- will ask again if i get stuck. Thank you Ryan!